# Remove empty bar space in Group bar chart using Plot.ly javascript?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have rendered a group bar chart with 3 bars in each group. But some times one or two bars could be empty. In that case, It's occupying space for **ALL THREE bars**. 
How can I remove this 0 height bar's space? 
I have used `width: 0.1` and `bargap: 0.6`

Source link https://codepen.io/blacmoon/pen/MRqQoj

For ex: Check the 1997 in X,  Its having one bar value. But occupied 3bars space.

Comment: It would look damn ugly if you remove the space :)

Comment: :) @skobaljic
Yes. But If no records for that bar,  we can remove that empty space.

Comment: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/traces/bar/plot.js?utf8=%E2%9C%93
I'm analyzing this page to override it. But didn't find it still

Comment: There should be a way to stack bars right? something like `layout = {barmode: 'stack'}`... that should be a solution - check it [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart)

Comment: @skobaljic I'm using group bar to create a time line of events. Converting it into stack will not be wise choice for that

Answer (score 0):

Late to this, but maybe it will help someone.  If you want the graph to show the "Rest of World" value in the same position, you need to provide a value for China and China Nation.  If there is no value, put *null* so plotly knows there is no value.  Put 0 if the value is in fact 0 which will show a slight bump where the bar would be [see the difference in this Codepen for 1997](https://codepen.io/kevinonearth/pen/WNdVWRZ).

Relevant parts:

```
var trace2 = {
  x: [1995, 1998, 1996, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003],
  y: [0, 16, 0, null, 13, 10, 11, 0,0,0],
  name: 'China',

var trace3 = {
  x: [1997, 1998, 1999, 2000,2001, 2002, 2003],
  y: [0, 16, 13, 10, 11, 0,0,0],
  name: 'China Nation',
```